# How can I get a summary similar to git add --interactive?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I am looking for a Bash command (or sequence of commands) that prints a summary of what files are changed in a Git working copy. The summary should include the number of insertions and deletions in each file, and maybe whether they are staged.

The command `git add --interactive` (which is synonymous with `git add -i`) gives exactly the summary I want (plus other stuff). The problem is that it doesn't just print and exit, it starts up a whole non-Bash shell. Here is the part of `git add -i` that I like:

```
bash$ git add -i
         staged     unstaged path
1:    unchanged        +3/-0 trunk/src/analyzer.c
2:    unchanged       +5/-13 trunk/src/converter.c
```

That's a great summary. Unfortunately, after it prints, you are not back in Bash. To get back to Bash, you need to type `q` and then enter, to quit. I really want it to just print the summary and then stop.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Type the following in the Bash terminal: `git add -i; q`. This doesn't work, it still needs you to press `q` manually, and then it gives an error because of the second `q`.
2. Put the following in a script `gitsummary.sh` and then run it: `git add -i`, with or without `; q` at the end. Same problem.

How can I get this summary in a totally non-interactive way? I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Use a Bash trick that waits a fraction of a second and then simulates a key press.
2. Use a different Git command that prints the same information but doesn't start a strange little shell.

My main setup: Mac OS X 10.9 and Terminal (running /bin/bash).

My secondary setup: Windows 7 or 8 and Cygwin running Bash.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should give you what you want:

```
git diff --numstat
git diff --stat
```

Comment: Problem 1: Both of those commands totally omit staged files, and I really want to see staged files too. Problem 2: Both of those commands don't mention `??` files (I am talking about files that are not yet tracked but are not ignored either, i.e. new files). However, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: This is _closer_ to what I want, but still not what I want: `git diff --numstat HEAD`. I do not like `git diff --stat HEAD` because it does not itemize insertions and deletions separately, it seems to add them together and then show plus signs and minus signs in relative proportions.

Comment: @SerMetAla: What would insertions/deletions even mean for untracked files? If you really want them there, write a script that merges the `git diff` output with something that counts the number of lines in untracked files (using `git ls-files -o` to find them).

Comment: I don't want the number of insertions/deletions in untracked files, I just want the untracked files to show up in the list period. It could say N/A where the numbers go, but put the filename in the proper place.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Just use `git ls-files -o` to list those files (and format the output however you like).